# How to prove that time complexity for this integer partition algorithm is O(n(logn))?

Tags: c#, time-complexity

So this is integer partitioning algorithm which calculates how many ways you can write an integer in  a way of writing it as a sum of positive integers

Example for 5:

4 +  1

3 + 2

2 + 2 + 1

2 + 1 + 1 + 1

1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1

How do you calculate time complexity of such algorithm?

```
 int P(int suma, int d)
        {


            if (d == 0)                                    
                return 0;                                  
            if (suma == 0)                                
                return 1;                                 
            if (suma < 0)                              
                return 0;                              

            return P(suma, d - 1) + P(suma- d, d);         
        }
```

Comment: The O value can not really be calculated or measured. It is a general idea of how things will behave on average: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory

Comment: As you are using recursion, it is most propably not a linear progression. | I am not a mathematician, but it also looks suspiciously like Ackermanns Function: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i7sm9dzFtEI

Comment: Interesting question, but while it is not strictly a programming question. I think you might have a better luck getting it answered at https://math.stackexchange.com/ or https://cs.stackexchange.com/ . For example you can see related questions here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3340723/how-many-ways-to-partition-n-elements-into-two-nonempty-subsets, also look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set Good luck!